# AWS Application Load Balancer is accessible by IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-elb, amazon-alb

I have a basic Application load balancer setup that routes web traffic to a few different EC2 instances. The load balancer has two public IP addresses, and both will display my site if entered in the browser. In other words the site can be accessed by the load balancer IPs

How do I configure the load balancer so that the public IP addresses are not accessible in the browser? I would expect the page to fail to load given my load balancer IPs.

All my DNS records point to the load balancer's DNS name and not either of the public IPs

Any help would be great!

Comment: What you have described is pretty much a fundamental behavior of the Internet. I suspect you are misguided about something. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  Why don’t you want people to access the site via IP address?

Comment: The goal is to not be able to access the site directly by the IP address. When accessing by IP the connection is insecure as the SSL certificate is on the domain. Additionally allowing access by IP could lead to duplicated indexing in google which is generally bad for SEO. I think redirecting the IP to the domain would solve the issue, but the IPs can change on the load balancer so how can I set that up?

Answer (score 2):

When a user enters a DNS name in a web browser, the browser/computer uses DNS to resolve the name into an IP address. Then, the browser connects to that IP address.

DNS is merely a "lookup" service that converts a name to an IP address.

Therefore, it is not possible to disable IP addresses while still allowing DNS to work.

**Here's an analogy:** Somebody knows your name and want to phone you, so they lookup your phone number in a telephone directory (old fashioned, I know). They then call you on the phone number. It is not possible to allow them to call you without them knowing your phone number.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but when someone types my load balancer IP into a browser they should not be served the site on the IP address. Either they should be routed to the domain name or an error page should show. For example stackoverflow.com has an public IP 151.101.193.69 but when I put that in my browser I'm not shown their site. Alternatively, Google has an IP 216.58.217.174 but it redirects to google.com, the site isn't served on the IP, it's served on the domain.

Comment: @DaveFaliskie your observations are correct, but the part you are missing is that this is because *their web servers* do not blindly serve up the site content.  Your web server needs to be configured accordingly.  It is not the balancer that is behaving incorrectly -- it's your web server that is returning content when it should not.  Its default behavior should be a redirect or an error, with your domain content returned only when your domain is requested by the browser.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Do you know how I can configure my web server to redirect to an error when hit by an IP? I'm using apache and have some basic reroutes set up, what does this default look like?

Comment: To clarify, 
I have an Application load balancer setup, which has two public IP addresses. Behind the load balancer are a few EC2 instances with only private IPs. 

Should I be able to navigate to my site with one of the load balancer IPs? If yes, does that mean it's the typical/ expected behavior of a load balancer? If no, how exactly do I configure the load balancer or apache web server to only serve my site on the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule that forwards from your known host name to whichever target group you'd like to forward to.

eg: if host is `www.example.com` forward to `my-site`

Then, as your last, default rule have everything else redirect to a custom `host`, `path`, `query` which uses all of the original values of the URL except the host name, which you can specify to your domain name (eg: `www.example.com`).

So now if someone enters the ip address, he will be redirected to the same page but with the domain name you'd like.

Of course, you can have the default rule do anything you'd like (eg: a fixed response error page).